# Regular Expression - Match strings in specific order

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match several strings in a specific order separated by anything including newlines.

So, if the 3 strings are `cat`, `<dog`, `</bird>` then:

`cat abcd
abc <dog abc
</bird>`

matches, but

`cat abcd
abc </bird> abc
<dog`

does not.

EDIT: one more example:

`catabcd
abc <dog abc
</bird>`

and any such variation where the search terms are not separated by word boundaries should also match.

One final example, it should be greedy in that:

```
cat abcd
</bird>
<dog
<dog
cat
</bird>
```

Does NOT match.

I have tried lookahead:
`(?=.*?cat)(?=.*?dog)(?=.*?bird).*` but this does not enforce order (and this particular example only works on one line).

*Note: I am using notepad++, but can resort to perl if necessary.*

Comment: Do you want to match the entire line containing "cat" and "bird" or just use them as start/endpoints?

Comment: What about: `cat[.\n]+?dog[.\n]+?bird`

Comment: Mateen Ulhaq, Matching either entire line or just start/endpoints is ok, also cat[.\n]+?dog[.\n]+?bird yields no matches on regexr.com

Comment: Your last example should not be match? Am I right?

Comment: @k-five, that is correct, last example should not match.

Comment: Check my answer and see that it is correct or NOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may you need something looks like this:

#### [`cat(?:(?!bird|cat).)*dog(?:(?!dog|bird).)*bird`](https://regex101.com/r/uaZ5Qp/2)

It matches only one `cat` and after this only one `dog` and then only one `bird`

with the help of **negative look-ahead assertion**

Comment: This is getting closer, however there are 2 additional cases that don't work, `cat dog cat bird` and `cat dog dog bird`. Perhaps more clearly, I cant have a dog (or multiple dogs) between a cat and a bird, regardless of the existence of other cats between the dog and the bird. Please note, I've pretty much given up on a regex solution for this and am going to code.

Comment: What they are? comment here

Comment: To clarify my above comment, when I say "I cant have a dog (or multiple dogs) between a cat and a bird...", I mean I want to detect this condition and thus it should be a match.

Comment: @GlenYates I am not sure to understand you well. So it should match multiple `dog`s between only one `cat` and only one `bird`? If it is not the case please add any possibilities you have to your question.

Comment: Basically yes, but additionally the existence of 1-n cats between the dog and the bird should still result in a match, so we have: `cat dog bird`, `cat dog dog bird`, and `cat dog cat bird` should all match.

Comment: @GlenYates try these one

Comment: You sir, are a genius!

Answer (score 1):

> can resort to perl if necessary

Here is the way to do it with Perl.

> separated by anything including newlines

In Perl, use the modifier `s` for `.` to **match anything including newline** (this modifier means *matching as a single line*).

Thus, you can match your input this way: `m/.*cat.*dog.*bird.*/s`.

This is the source code, its output is `matches`:

```
#!/bin/perl -W

$content = " cat abcd
abc dog abc
bird";

print "matches\n" if ($content =~ m/.*cat.*dog.*bird.*/s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you found lookaheads, since they are usually more complex to understand than the basic features in regex... which are what I would use for your task given the info you provided:

```
\bcat\b.*?\bdog\b.*?\bbird\b
```

[image: Screenshot]

Make sure that 'Regular expression' and '. matches newline' are both checked, and that your cursor is at the beginning of the file.

The `\b` that I used are to ensure that the words you stated match. They ensure that the word is not preceded nor followed by another word character (so that `cat` will match, but `cats` will not).

Comment: Jerry, thanks for the answer, but please see the edit, in that the search terms might not be bounded by word boundaries. Also, is there a way to get this to work across lines on regexr.com which is where I was testing this?

Comment: @GlenYates Ok, then I think you can remove them. I added that description at the end so that you could change it yourself if you didn't need them ^^ And I don't like regexr, it doesn't have all the things I believe it should have. I use regex101.com where I can have the `s` flag to make `.` match newlines, and there's a new feature there called unit tests that was added since I used it last time that looks useful! xD https://regex101.com/r/hpQ8Jl/1/tests

Comment: Please see my hopefully last edit, I can't have specifically the last search term in the middle of what would otherwise be a match, i.e. `cat </bird> <dog </bird>` should NOT match.

Comment: @GlenYates Ah, I just saw your comment now. Welp, too late now.